# Jinja2 url generation

Tags: python, django, url-routing, jinja2

```
<a href="{{ url('affiliate', affiliate=object.slug) }}">{{ object.name }} </a>
```

Cause an error:
reverse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'affiliate'

Answer (score 5):

As your `url()` function seem to be an alias to the Django's `reverse()`, the function signature is different from the regular template tag. So just use the `reverse()` [syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

```
<a href="{{ url('affiliate', args=[object.slug]) }}">{{ object.name }}</a>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10847906)

Comment: Excuse me? Could you please elaborate on that? My answer is on-topic and clearly doesn't contain critique or a clarification request.

Comment: Yes, this was an automatic comment via "review" section. Your answer was labeled as "too short" so more suitable as comment that as answer. I suggest you to better explain "why" your solution is a correct one and maybe the best one, so make it a "real" complete answer

Comment: @LucaDetomi, sounds reasonable, thanks for the thorough explanation. I've updated the answer.