# Cannot reverse a url from name in Jinja2

Tags: django, jinja2

I have a Django project with Jinja 2.10 templating. I have a standard Jinja environment that aliases `url` to Django's `reverse`. In urlpatterns I have the following entry:

`path('test', views.test, name='test')`

And I want to dynamically create a URL to this view from another simple template:

`{{ url('test') }}`

However, when I open the view that renders this template, I receive an error:

`Reverse for 'test' not found. 'test' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

I see people successfully using this method (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716738/4855256)), so why isn't it working here?

Comment: Put your views here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: the proper format is `{{ url('app_name:view_name') }}`, not simply `{{ url('view_name') }}`